# Background color for UISearchController in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a SearchController's search bar inserted programatically into a UITableView's tableHeaderView.  When I pull up to view the search bar or refresh the table, I get this weird darker gray that you can see in the following image, in between the refresher activity indicator and the search bar (this background color persists even when I remove the refresher view):

[image]

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

I've tried changing this background color in every way I can think of:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
tableView.tableHeaderView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Nothing works.  This dark gray isn't one of the custom colors I use in my project so I know I didn't set it manually.  As soon as I take out the searchController everything works just like before: that dark gray is replaced by the lighter gray seen everywhere else.

Comment: searchController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() ?

Comment: I don't actually want it red, just checking what works.  None of those change that dark gray background color.

Comment: Try this it might be helpful

self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame.size.height)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Set the UITableView's backgroundView to a new useless view:

```
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [UIView new];
```

Seems illogical, but works like a charm :)

Answer (score 16):

Cameron E's correct answer in Swift:

`tableView.backgroundView = UIView()`

Note that `self.tableView.backgroundView = nil` does **not** work.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
[searchController.searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[searchController.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Just set an empty view as the UITableView's backgroundview

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];
```

Answer (score -1):

try to change color of

self.navigationController?.navigationBar = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)